# Compare keys in arrays and make new array with comparison values

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

I have 2 arrays that I need to compare and then create a new array with the key staying the same, but adding a new array of as value with the two values from the two arrays.

```
$array1 = (['SE'] => (string) '123', ['DE'] => (string) '456', ['DK'] => (string) '678');
$array2 = (['SE'] => (string) '999', ['DE'] => (string) '888', ['US'] => (string) '777');
```

So what I want to achieve is to get the value from both arrays where the key is equal to one another.
I then need to echo it in a similar fashion;

```
echo '<table>';
foreach($newCompparedArray as $k => $v){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$k.'</td><td>'.$v->value1.'</td><td>'.$v->value2.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Another thing is I need the key to only get the values if the key was present in the initial array (i.e. if a key isn't in array1 but is present in array2, don't add this key or it's values to the new array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you what you want:

```
$array1 = array('SE' =>  '123', 'DE' =>  '456', 'DK' =>  '678');
$array2 = array('SE' =>  '999', 'DE' =>  '888', 'US' =>  '777');

$keysInBothArrays = array_intersect(array_keys($array1),array_keys($array2));
$newCompparedArray = array();
foreach ($keysInBothArrays as $key) {
    $newCompparedArray[$key] = array($array1[$key],$array2[$key]);
}
// print_r($newCompparedArray); exit;

echo '<table>';
foreach($newCompparedArray as $k => $v){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$k.'</td><td>'.$v[0].'</td><td>'.$v[1].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

The trick is to get the keys which are in both arrays first.

Comment: YES! Thank you  :)  I've been looking at this for too long and was just going in circles.

Answer (score 0):

Loop the first array, check for the value in the second array and if it exists add both:

```
foreach($array1 as $k => $v) {
    $newCompparedArray[$k] = isset($array2[$k]) ? array($v, $array2[$k]) : $v;
}
```

Then your display loop would be:

```
foreach($newCompparedArray as $k => $v) {
    echo '<td>'.$k.'</td><td>'.$v[0].'</td><td>'.$v[1].'</td>';
}
```

Obviously in the first loop if you define `array('value1'=>$v, 'value2'=>$array2[$k])` then you could use `$v['value1]` and `$v['value2']`.

The shorter version:

```
$newCompparedArray = array_intersect_key(array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2), $array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood the output you wanted as

```
Array(
    [SE] => Array ( [0] => 123, [1] => 999 )
    [DE] => Array ( [0] => 456, [1] => 888 )
    [DK] => Array ( [0] => 678 )
    [US] => Array ( [0] => 777 )
)
```

I would use this code

```
$array1 =array ('SE' => '123', 'DE' => '456', 'DK' => '678');
$array2 =array ('SE' => '999', 'DE' => '888', 'US' => '777');

$t =array ();
foreach ( $array1 as $key => $value )
    $t [$key] =array ($value);
foreach ( $array2 as $key => $value ) {
    if ( !isset ($t [$key]) )
        $t [$key] =array ($value);
    else
        $t [$key] [] =$value;
}
//print_r ($t);
foreach ( $t as $key => $value ) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td>$key</td><td>" . implode ("</td><td>", $value) . '</td>';
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```